# creating do not disturb mode in python code (play sound or not play)

Tags: python, bots

I started creating my bot and decided to introduce into it the ability to send sound notifications using the `playsound` module. But I would like to make some kind of regime: "Do not disturb", i.e. make some argument (example: `dont_disturb == 0`) and if the message is written: "turn on notifications", then the bot will switch this value to 1 and will play the sound.

**Here is a example of code and what I roughly want to do:**

```
dont_disturb == 0
print(Fore.CYAN + "[", current_time, "]",Fore.WHITE + "[", nickname, "]", Fore.WHITE + content, Fore.CYAN + "[", title, "(", chatName, ")", "]")

playsound('notification.mp3')

if content.lower().startswith("disable notifications"):
   dont_disturb == 0
   sub_client.send_message(message=f"Sound notifies was succsesfully 
   deactivated.", chatId=chatId, replyTo=id)

   if content.lower().startswith("activate notifications"):
   dont_disturb == 1
   sub_client.send_message(message=f"Sound notifies was succsesfully 
   activated.", chatId=chatId, replyTo=id)
```

Comment: Please, edit your code. It's impossible to read and understand what's going on. Use ~~~ or ``` at the beginning and the end of the code block.

Comment: Please describe your problem. Now I see what you want, and an example of that, but not where you are stuck.

Comment: @user_cr, hello! look, I have the playsound notification.mp3 command written in my code, it plays every time a message arrives in the terminal, I want to make some kind of do not disturb mode and make it so that if the mode is turned on, the sound will not turn on every time a message is sent in the bot terminal. But I do not know how to write it correctly.

Comment: `if not dont_disturb: playsound("notification.mp3")` ?

Comment: @user_cr, doesnt work